# Como atualizar campos em AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Ao inserir itens na lista utilizando o seguinte trecho de código:

```
$scope.items.push({
                codigo: $scope.s.codigo,
                ncm: $scope.s.ncm,
                descricao: $scope.s.descricao,
                preco: $scope.s.preco,
                quantidade: $scope.s.quantidade
            });
```

cada produto possuirá Tributos diferentes,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar no botão Tributos, é exibido a seguinte tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Simulação: https://jsfiddle.net/t9grvL4z/1/

Como atualizar os impostos de cada produto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta criar um método que, ao clicar em "Tributos", o objeto em questão será mapeado por outro objeto temporário e assim você conseguirá alterar, individualmente, os atributos de cada produto.

**Solução com base na "Simulação" apresentada:**

→ Criação do método addTributos;

→ Inserção do ng-model dentro do
   modal;

→ Inserção do `track by $index` (laço em AngularJS, no HTML);

→ Criação de um objeto temporário com o nome produtoTrib.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('controlador', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.user = {};
    $scope.produtoTrib = {};
 $scope.items = [];
 var sum = 1;
 
 $scope.addItem = function (user){
   $scope.items.push({
    nome: $("input[name='nome']").val(),
    email: $("input[name='email']").val(),
    soma: sum++
   });
    user.nome = '';
    user.email = ''; 
 };
      
     
    $scope.addTributos = function (produto){
        $scope.produtoTrib = produto;
 };
      
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controlador">

<form ng-submit="submitForm()">
    <label>Nome: </label><input type="text" name="nome" ng-model="user.nome">
    <label>E-mail: </label><input type="text" name="email" ng-model="user.email">
    
    <input type="text" hidden name="email" ng-model="user.telefone">
    <input type="text" hidden name="email" ng-model="user.cpf">
    
    <input type="button" value="Adicionar" ng-click="addItem(user)" />
</form>
<br />

<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
ID: {{item.soma}}<br />
Nome: {{item.nome}}<br />
E-mail: {{item.email}}<br /><br />
<!-- {{item.telefone}} - {{item.cpf}} -->
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="addTributos(item)">Tributos</button>
<hr />
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Tributos</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label>Telefone: </label><input type="text" name="telefone" ng-model="produtoTrib.telefone">
        <label>CPF: </label><input type="text" name="cpf" ng-model="produtoTrib.cpf">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Atualizar</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Como faço para enviar/capturar esses valores, respectivo a cada idem, via POST no PHP? @hugolima

Comment: Depende do seu cenário, você quer enviar ao clicar em salvar (no modal) ? Se sim, você pode enviar o objeto completo($scope.produtoTrib) por $http do angular(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Entendo, porém posso lhe explicar alguns detalhes via chat? @hugolima.

Comment: Pode sim, criei um sala e te convidei

Comment: podemos marcar um horário para que conversar no chat sem interrupções?